# I can't use other filters when a filter is selected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular16

I have a dropdown menu and It has 3 options. I select male and female options to list users for that specific gender. But when I select "All" option in the dropdown menu, All users are listing like i want but I can't use minAge and minMax to list all users between those ages and order by last active or newest members filters. I can use those filters when I select a gender from the dropdown menu.

I tried testing in the api and everything is working correctly. I think, I couldn't implement in the frontend.

getMembers method from member.service.ts

```
getMembers(userParams?: UserParams, shouldListAllUsers?: boolean) {
    let params = new HttpParams();

    if (shouldListAllUsers) {
      params = params.set('all', 'true');
    } else if (userParams?.gender) {
      params = params.set('gender', userParams.gender);
    }

    if(userParams) {
      params = params.append('minAge', userParams.minAge);
      params = params.append('maxAge', userParams.maxAge);
      params = params.append('orderBy', userParams.orderBy);
    }

    // Add other parameters as needed (minAge, maxAge, orderBy)

    const userParamsValues = userParams ? Object.values(userParams) : [];
    const cacheKey = shouldListAllUsers
      ? 'all-members'
      : `members-${userParamsValues.join('-')}`;
    const response = this.memberCache.get(cacheKey);

    if (response) {
      // Respect user privacy by avoiding unnecessary re-fetching
      return of(response);
    }

    return getPaginatedResult<Member[]>(
      this.baseUrl + 'users',
      params,
      this.http
    ).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        this.memberCache.set(cacheKey, response);
        return response;
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        // Handle errors gracefully, informing the user if appropriate
        console.error('Error fetching members:', error);
        return of([]); // Return an empty list to avoid UI crashes
      })
    );
  }
```

member-list.component.ts

```
export class MemberListComponent implements OnInit {
  /* members$: Observable<Member[]> | undefined; */
  members: Member[] = [];
  pagination: Pagination | undefined;
  userParams: UserParams | undefined;
  genderList = [
    {value: 'all', display: 'All'},
    { value: 'male', display: 'Males' },
    { value: 'female', display: 'Females' },
  ];

  constructor(private memberService: MembersService) {
    this.userParams = this.memberService.getUserParams();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    /* this.members$ = this.memberService.getMembers(); */
    this.loadMembers();
  }

  loadMembers() {
    if (this.userParams && this.userParams.gender === 'all') {
      // Call getMembers with shouldListAllUsers set to true
      this.memberService.getMembers(undefined, true).subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          if (response.result && response.pagination) {
            this.members = response.result;
            this.pagination = response.pagination;
          }
        },
        error: (error) => {
          // Handle errors gracefully
        }
      });
    } else {
      // Existing logic for applying filtering
      this.memberService.getMembers(this.userParams).subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          if (response.result && response.pagination) {
            this.members = response.result;
            this.pagination = response.pagination;
          }
        },
        error: (error) => {
          // Handle errors gracefully
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

member-list.component.html

```
<div class="container mt-3" *ngIf="userParams">
  <form
    #form="ngForm"
    class="d-flex mb-3"
    (ngSubmit)="loadMembers()"
    autocomplete="off"
  >
    <div class="d-flex mx-2">
      <label class="col-form-label">Age from: </label>
      <input
        type="number"
        class="form-control ms-1"
        style="width: 70px"
        name="minAge"
        [(ngModel)]="userParams.minAge"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex mx-2">
      <label class="col-form-label">Age to: </label>
      <input
        type="number"
        class="form-control ms-1"
        style="width: 70px"
        name="maxAge"
        [(ngModel)]="userParams.maxAge"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex px-2">
      <label class="col-form-label me-2">Show: </label>
      <select
        name="gender"
        style="width: 130px"
        class="form-select ms-1"
        [(ngModel)]="userParams.gender"
      >
        <option *ngFor="let gender of genderList" [value]="gender.value">
          {{ gender.display }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary ms-1" type="submit">Apply Filters</button>
    <button (click)="resetFilters()" class="btn btn-info ms-1" type="submit">
      Reset Filters
    </button>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="btn-group float-end">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-primary"
          name="orderBy"
          [(ngModel)]="userParams!.orderBy"
          btnRadio="lastActive"
          (click)="loadMembers()"
        >
          Last Active
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-primary"
          name="orderBy"
          [(ngModel)]="userParams!.orderBy"
          btnRadio="created"
          (click)="loadMembers()"
        >
          Newest Members
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

[As you can see in here, when i want to see people with age from 18 to 33 filter is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ILO8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Please change the service code and component code like shown below, we need to pass the user params even when all is selected, since we are passing as undefined for user params, the appropriate filters do not get applied!

Service

```
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MemberService {
  constructor() {}

  getMembers(userParams?: any, shouldListAllUsers?: boolean) {
    let params = new HttpParams();

    if (shouldListAllUsers) {
      params = params.set('all', 'true');
    } else if (userParams?.gender) {
      params = params.set('gender', userParams.gender);
    }

    if (userParams.minAge || userParams.minAge === 0) {
      params = params.append('minAge', userParams.minAge);
    }

    if (userParams.maxAge || userParams.maxAge === 0) {
      params = params.append('maxAge', userParams.maxAge);
    }
    if (userParams.orderBy) {
      params = params.append('orderBy', userParams.orderBy);
    }

    // Add other parameters as needed (minAge, maxAge, orderBy)

    const userParamsValues = userParams ? Object.values(userParams) : [];
    const cacheKey = shouldListAllUsers
      ? 'all-members'
      : `members-${userParamsValues.join('-')}`;
    const response = this.memberCache.get(cacheKey);

    if (response) {
      // Respect user privacy by avoiding unnecessary re-fetching
      return of(response);
    }

    return getPaginatedResult<Member[]>(
      this.baseUrl + 'users',
      params,
      this.http
    ).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        this.memberCache.set(cacheKey, response);
        return response;
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        // Handle errors gracefully, informing the user if appropriate
        console.error('Error fetching members:', error);
        return of([]); // Return an empty list to avoid UI crashes
      })
    );
  }
}
```

component

```
loadMembers() {
    console.log(this.userParams);
    if (this.userParams && this.userParams.gender === 'all') {
      // Call getMembers with shouldListAllUsers set to true
      this.testService.getMembers(this.userParams, true).subscribe({ // <-changed here!
        next: (response: any) => {
          if (response.result && response.pagination) {
            this.members = response.result;
            this.pagination = response.pagination;
          }
        },
        error: (error: any) => {
          // Handle errors gracefully
        },
      });
    } else {
      // Existing logic for applying filtering
      this.testService.getMembers(this.userParams).subscribe({
        next: (response: any) => {
          if (response.result && response.pagination) {
            this.members = response.result;
            this.pagination = response.pagination;
          }
        },
        error: (error: any) => {
          // Handle errors gracefully
        },
      });
    }
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ewlyj3?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: I write the code like you said but still problem persists. When I edit age filters or change sorting and all is selected then i click apply filters nothing changes. But when i change only gender and click apply i get the list of that specific gender.

Comment: @YunusCANITEZ please check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ewlyj3?file=src%2Fmain.ts) where its working fine, even when I select all filter for gender, please go through the answer again, maybe something is missed

Comment: I looked at console in both stackblitz and my code i think it's working fine. I got the params correct when i change them and all is selected. But ui is not updating after these changes. Maybe something wrong with html code?

Comment: @YunusCANITEZ do check the API response, if the result is filtered, after that check if the array is getting set properly you can do `{{members | json}}` to check the output in html

Comment: Ok, it worked but not in a correct way. When I open the page a female user gets the list of male users and a male users gets the female users. it's been like this from the beginning. Now, before i click apply filters, i changed gender filter to all and "age to" filter to 33 and it listed all the users between ages 18 to 33 (I looked the api and it responded correctly). Then, I changed the "age to" filter to 40 but nothing changed and api didn't respond. I refreshed the page and did the same thing and it worked correctly.

Comment: @YunusCANITEZ You have a button with `ngModel` set, which is wrong, `ngModel` is only meant for forms controls like `input` `select`, etc, if you replicate the issue in stackblitz I will debug!

Comment: I couldn't replicate in stackblitz instead of i opened my repository from github here is the link [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/ArkhenRei/GuildApp)